# jQuery slide right to left not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have a panel thats position is supposed to toggle on a button click. I cannot even get a simple animate left to work, nevermind a toggle

```
#sideCol { position: absolute; right: -70%; width: 70%; }
```

My idea is to animate the `right` positioning to 0% and then back to -70% on click events

**jQuery**

```
$('#sidecoltab').click(function() {
    $('#sideCol').animate({ "right": "0%" }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Script seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8E6H5/

Comment: Make link to full source.(jsfiddle.net etc.)

Comment: dumb error by me the C was not capitilized on my div, do you know how to toggle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the element use a class:

```
$('#sidecoltab').click(function() {
    var $elem = $('#sideCol');
    $elem.toggleClass("open"); 
    $elem.animate({"right": $elem.hasClass("open") ? "-70%":"0%" }, 300);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8E6H5/2/